# Installation error with Composer

Tags: 8, installation, composer

I'm trying to install Drupal 8 with Composer. Drupal Console is already installed (in case that's relevant), so I go to my localhost folder (working locally) and type:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev cmpsprjct --stability dev --no-interaction
```

Everything runs well with the composer installation in the terminal. When I try to proceed with the installation in the browser I get following error:

```
Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
Original

TypeError: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned in Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() (line 55 of /var/www/html/cmpsprjct/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php).

Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() (Line: 113)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin\Discovery\AnnotatedClassDiscovery->getDefinitions() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 283)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 174)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 109)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->buildInfo('seven') (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo('form') (Line: 806)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->prepareForm('install_select_language_form', Array, Object) (Line: 272)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('install_select_language_form', Object) (Line: 898)
install_get_form('Drupal\Core\Installer\Form\SelectLanguageForm', Array) (Line: 1324)
install_select_language(Array) (Line: 670)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 548)
install_run_tasks(Array) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)

Additional

TypeError: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned in Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() (line 55 of /var/www/html/cmpsprjct/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php).

Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::reset() (Line: 113)
Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin\Discovery\AnnotatedClassDiscovery->getDefinitions() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 283)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 174)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 109)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->buildInfo('seven') (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\Render\ElementInfoManager->getInfo('html') (Line: 298)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 139)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}() (Line: 576)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 140)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot(Array) (Line: 66)
Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, 'Error', 'install_page', Array) (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, 'Error', 'install_page', Array) (Line: 1004)
install_display_output(Array, Array, Array) (Line: 264)
_drupal_log_error(Array, 1) (Line: 584)
_drupal_exception_handler(Object)
```

I have searched in Google and found that a composer update could solve the problem, but it didn't. 
Any hints about how to proceed?

Working with Ubuntu 17.04 and php 7.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please make sure your webserver (nginx/apache) is using the same PHP version as your cli one. For example, you may encounter this issue if your cli PHP version is PHP 7.1 and your webserver is using PHP 7.0.

Comment: This helped me. To clarify -- after I made sure my php cli version was correct I ran `composer update` again and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Perfect. When upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, the CLI version of PHP updated to 7.2.15, but the version on the webserver was stuck at 7.0.33, the latest version I had installed on 16.04. Because Composer figures dependencies differently depending on the PHP version, when you run "composer update" with a CLI version incompatible with your server version you get this problem

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu 16.04 I had to run the following commands to adjust the PHP version used by Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I removed all php dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get remove php*
```

I installed php again:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-fpm php7.1-curl php7.1-gd php7.1-bz2 php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-json php7.1-tidy php7.1-mbstring php-redis php-memcached
```

Restarted Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

There is the installation screen!

Comment: php7.1-xml is missing. ihere. by adding this drush will work fine, too